# Logistic regression: Strange standard errors from glm() in R

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, standard-error, intercept

To my surprise I found that standard errors and thus Wald confidence intervals became smaller when I removed the intercept from a simple logistic regression model, using `glm()` and R.

```
# load an object named "my.df" to the global enviroment
load(url("http://hansekbrand.se/code/test.RData"))
# fit a model with intercept to data
my.fit <- glm(deprived.of.education ~ religion, data = my.df, family = binomial("logit"))
# fit a model without any intercept to data
my.fit.without.intercept <- glm(deprived.of.education ~ 0 + religion, data = my.df, family = binomial("logit"))

# inspect the first fit
summary(my.fit)$coefficients
#                        Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept)          -2.8718056 0.03175130 -90.44687 0.000000e+00
# religionChristianity  0.4934891 0.03234887  15.25522 1.519805e-52
# religionHinduism      0.5257316 0.03376535  15.57015 1.161317e-54
# religionIslam         1.5734832 0.03231692  48.68914 0.000000e+00
# religionNonreligious  1.5975456 0.03555164  44.93592 0.000000e+00

# inspect the second fit
summary(my.fit.without.intercept)$coefficients
#                       Estimate  Std. Error    z value Pr(>|z|)
# religionBuddhism     -2.871806 0.031751299  -90.44687        0
# religionChristianity -2.378317 0.006189045 -384.27842        0
# religionHinduism     -2.346074 0.011487113 -204.23530        0
# religionIslam        -1.298322 0.006019850 -215.67354        0
# religionNonreligious -1.274260 0.015992939  -79.67642        0
```

I understand why the *z* values are different, because the null hypotheses in the two cases are different. In the first case, with the intercept, the null is "same as the reference category", while without the intercept, the null becomes "zero".
But I do not understand the large difference in standard errors between the two models.

Without the intercept, the standard errors seem to vary with *n* of each level, i.e. there are many cases of "Christianity" and "Islam", and they have small standard errors, but with the intercept, there is essentially no variation in the standard errors.

Could someone please explain the reason for the differences in the magnitude of the standard errors between the two models?

I would like to calculate probabilities and confidence intervals around them, and I have done so using the estimates from the first model. If I would do that with the estimates from the second model, the confidence intervals would be much smaller, but would they be reliable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your coefficients, even when they share common names, are not the same, i.e. their interpretation is different.

In the first model, the effect of `religionChristianity` is a variation in the outcome wrt the baseline (`religionBuddhism`), a *relative* variation. In the second model the effect of `religionChristianity` is an *absolute* variation.

The effects are numerically equal, $-2.8718056+0.4934891=-2.378317+5e-07$, but in the first case the effect is a sum of two effects, i.e. you should compare the joint significance of `Intercept` and `religionChristianity` in the first model with the significance of `religionChristianity` in the second one. You should compare a joint confidence interval (first model) with a simple one (second model).

The simple CI for `religionChristianity` is:

```
> confint(my.fit.without.intercept)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                         2.5 %    97.5 %
...
religionChristianity -2.390467 -2.366207
```

There are several ways to compute joint intervals. Using [arm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arm/index.html):

```
> library(arm)
> n.sims <- 1000
> sim.i <- sim(my.fit, n.sims)
> intercept.plus.christianity <- sim.i@coef[,1] + sim.i@coef[,2]
> quantile(intercept.plus.christianity, c(0.025, 0.975))
     2.5%     97.5% 
-2.390826 -2.366828
```

Can you see any significant (relevant) difference?

Comment: No, I don't. Thanks for the code, it gives a practical way to get to my goal, and it proves that both sets of standard errors are correct. However, I would like to have the formula too. For the second, non-intercept model, getting eg. the lower bound for "Christianity" is simple enough: $ -2.390448 = -2.378317 - 1.96 \times 0.006189045 $. My naive idea was to create the "combined" interval for the first model by $ -2.8718056 + 0.4934891 - 1.96 * 0.03234887 $, but that gave a much larger confidence interval.

Comment: Your answer is useful, and I am thankful for it, but to close the question I would like to see a formula that arrives at the lower bound for "Christianity" from the estimates in the intercept model.

Comment: Sorry, but... why? The models are _numerically_ equivalent (this is what I wanted to highlight), but _statistically_ different, they address different scientific questions. If you are interested in "relative" effects you have to a) choose a baseline (Buddhism or something else, but you shoud explain why one or another) and b) run the first model and not bother to run the second one. If you are interested in "absolute" effects (no baseline) you should run the second model and not bother to run the first one. IMHO you can and should compare several models only if they address the same question.

Comment: Because I want to learn. What brought me into this was the desire to understand when I could do without an intercept term. Do you imply that there is no formula for me to understand in this case? Is sampling the only way?

Comment: Joint confidence "intervals" are actually confidence _regions_ (see, e.g., [here](http://academic.macewan.ca/burok/Stat378/notes/moremultiple.pdf) and [here](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~maitra/stat501/lectures/InferenceForMeans-Confidence.pdf)), this is why sampling is so convenient.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the links. Even if I don't understand the details, I do understand where I went wrong. To summarize: I used a faulty method when trying to calculate confidence intervals from the intercept model, which in turn lead me to belive that there was something wrong the standard errors of the non-intercept model.