# Closed form for the variance of a sum of two estimates in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, variance, interaction

In logistic regression with an intercept term and with at least one dependent variable which is categorical, is there a closed form for the variance of the sum of the intercept and the coefficient of the categorical variable, or do you have to sample from a multivariate distribution with the means and variances of the intercept and the coefficient to get a reliable measure of the variance of this sum?

$P(y) = \frac{exp(y)}{1 + exp(y)}$

$y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x + \epsilon$

where x is categorical.

Would the formula for the variance of a sum (of two random variables) be applicable here?

$Var(\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}) = Var(\beta_{0}) + Var(\beta_{1}) + 2Cov(\beta_{0}, \beta_{1})$

The reason I ask, is that in [this comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99633/logistic-regression-strange-standard-errors-from-glm-in-r#comment193235_99662) I got the impression that no closed form existed for the variance in question, and the advice was to sample from a multivariate distribution with the means and variances of $\beta_{0}$ and $\beta_{1}$

```
set.seed(1)
dependent.var <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
independent.var <- ifelse(dependent.var, sample(c("Red", "Blue"), replace = TRUE,
  size = 10, prob = c(0.8, 0.2)), sample(c("Red", "Blue"), size = 10,
  replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.4, 0.6)))
table(dependent.var, independent.var)
##               independent.var
## dependent.var Blue Red
##         FALSE   42  26
##         TRUE     7  25
my.fit <- glm(dependent.var ~ 1 + independent.var, family = binomial(logit))
coef(summary(my.fit))
                    Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)        -1.791759  0.4082482 -4.388897 0.0000113927
independent.varRed  1.752539  0.4951042  3.539737 0.0004005255
> vcov(my.fit)
                   (Intercept) independent.varRed
(Intercept)          0.1666666         -0.1666666
independent.varRed  -0.1666666          0.2451282
```

The logit of TRUE for a "Red" case is $ \beta_{0}+\beta_{1} \approx -0.039$. Is the variance for this estimate exactly

```
vcov(my.fit)[1,1] + vcov(my.fit)[2,2] + 2 * vcov(my.fit)[1,2]
[1] 0.07846154 ?
```

Or is this only an approximation, and a more accurate measure is to be found by sampling, e.g.

```
library(MASS)
var(rowSums(mvrnorm(n = 1E7, mu = coef(my.fit), Sigma = vcov(my.fit))))
[1] 0.07842985 ?
```

In this simple example, the sampling method does not seem to provide more accurate estimates of the variance (using 1E7 samples).

[Here](http://pages.iu.edu/~hgevans/p410-p609/material/06_fit/conf_reg.html) it is stated that "There is a correspondance between the covariance matrix of the fit parameters and Δχ2 confidence regions *only* for the case of Gaussian uncertainties on the input measurements.". Is that a reason against relying on the closed form above, or is there perhaps another reason for the advice to sample instead of deriving the variance analytically in cases like this?

EDIT: (In response to the answer given by StasK). The advice I originally got was to simulate from the full model, not from the `vcov()`, so here is the code to simulate from the full model:

```
library(arm)
sim.i <- sim(my.fit, 100000)
logit.for.TRUE.red <- sim.i@coef[,1] + sim.i@coef[,2]
var(logit.for.TRUE.red)
[1] 0.07781206
```

Comment: You should avoid conflating population parameters ($\beta$, fixed but unknown quantities with variance 0) with their estimates ($\hat \beta$, which are random variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard error is indeed an approximation, but not in the sense that you are thinking about. It is an approximation in the statistical sense that the standard errors in logistic regression are only good in large samples (and biased down somewhat in small samples). There is a number of other ways to obtain the standard errors (e.g., by resampling methods such as the bootstrap or jackknife), but their justification is likewise asymptotic (large samples), and the standard errors obtained using these different methods should be close to one another.

Adding simulation on top of that estimate is relatively pointless. Bayesians out there might argue that you get better approximation for the distribution of the estimates if you sample from the posterior, but I don't think that's your question, and that's not what you are doing. But other than that, you won't in any way be better off simulating if all you use is `vcov()`. (And if you are simulating from the multivariate normal, the mean and the variance are independent, so if you are only interested in the variance, it does not matter what mean you use; since you are interested in variance, the `vcov()` is the only relevant part.)

Simulating from multivariate normal per se isn't interesting: nearly every distributional result of nearly any meaningful function of the multivariate normal has been derived in an analytic form. A potentially useful application of simulation could be to simulate the binary outcomes from your model (parametric bootstrap), fit the logistic model to them, and compare the mean of reported standard errors to the standard deviation of the estimates, to see how biased the latter are, and to correct for that bias. That is a somewhat paranoid simulation though; I don't think anybody does that in applied statistics publications that I tend to see, even though that is (a) technically feasible and (b) somewhat statistically meaningful. It's just too much work with rather little improvement in the standard errors on the back end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I read your last two sentences I realised that the advice I originally got was _not_ simulating with `vcov()`, but simulating _from the full model_ using `sim()` from the package arm. I think I must have "invented" simulating from `vcov()` by mistake :-)

Is simulating from the full model better than deriving the standard error analytically?

Comment: I have updated the question with code that calculates the variance by simulating from the full model.

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter -- you are simulating from a multivariate normal distribution with a given mean and variance, and then estimating the variance of the resulting distribution. It's like buying a coffee in Starbucks, pouring into into your coffee machine instead of water, and with only a paper filter and no ground coffee, and running the drip cycle.

Comment: I updated the text a little bit, adding more explanations.